# Same algorithm from different packages generates completely different model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I am training a linear model with two packages separately.

However, I realize there is a huge difference between those two results, in terms of variables' coefficients.

```
def test(x, y, model):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(x_train, y_train)
    
    lr = sm.OLS(y_train, x_train).fit()
    print(lr.params)
    
    print(regr.coef_)
```

Above is the code I used. Surprisingly, the coefficient difference is so huge that it gives completely different predictions.[image]

Both models list variables in the same order, so I am really confused now. Any idea about what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the issue here is with how the intercept is handled in the two different packages.

With `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS`, an intercept is not included by default and needs to be added manually using `sm.add_constant(X)`.

In contrast, `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` includes an intercept by default, as indicated by the parameter `fit_intercept=True`. The intercept in `sklearn` is stored separately from the coefficients and can be viewed with `.intercept_`.

To ensure a fair comparison, both models should be configured to handle the intercept term in the same way. You can either add a constant to your `statsmodels` model:

```py
X = sm.add_constant(X)
```

Or disable the intercept in your `sklearn` model:

```py
LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
```

Make sure to adjust both models accordingly and then compare the coefficients again.

Comment: :O wow I didn't realize that, they produce same result now, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I also have to be cautious when comparing different implementations - it's easy to miss those default settings that differ from one to another.